# Problem with Java code that will print TRUE when a word has no vowels in an IF statement

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code the will print TRUE when i enter a word with no vowels and will print FALSE if I enter a word with vowels. I am having trouble when it comes to writing the string. I give one of the strings the value that holds all the values.
            String A = "aeiou";
The other 2 strings hold the rest of the alphabet.
When I type in a word that has vocals it prints FALSE however when I type in a word with no vowels it prints FALSE. 
I wanna know if there is a way to make the program read the values of the string as separate entities and not as a whole line.

```
package lab3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = reader.next();

        /* A and B, but not C */
        String A = "bcdfghjklm";
        String B = "npqrstvwxyz";
        String C = "aeiou";

        if (input.contains(A) && input.contains(B) || input.contains(C)) {
            System.out.println("TRUE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("FALSE");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to read the whole line and then convert the string to a char array using `toCharArray` or skip this step and loop through the string using `charAt`.

Comment: That contains() method checks if that complete string appears within the other one. You simply can't use that method like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a short function

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = reader.next();
        System.out.println(chk(input));
    }

    static public boolean chk(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if ("aeiou".indexOf(s.charAt(i)) != -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was going for but skip the local variable r and return false directly if a vowel is found since there is no point in continuing the loop then and return true if the end of the method is reached.

Comment: One minor thing that OP missed, the letter "y" is also an English vowel :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sure, but that's what he asked in the question, maybe he notices the error and adds it

Answer (score 1):

This is a working correct for your purpose:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = reader.next();
    String C = "aeiou";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char inputA = input.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < C.length(); j++) {
            char c = C.charAt(j);
            if (inputA == c) {
                System.out.println("TRUE");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("FALSE");
}
```

The key point is to use the method `charAt(int index);` so you can check each char in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to use any of the below two methods, **containsVowel** and **containsVowel1** as both of them do the same thing:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a text: ");
        String input = reader.nextLine();
        String[] vowels = { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" };
        System.out.println(!containsVowel(input, vowels));
        System.out.println(!containsVowel1(input, vowels));
    }

    public static boolean containsVowel(String input, String[] vowels) {
        return Arrays.stream(vowels).parallel().anyMatch(input::contains);
    }

    public static boolean containsVowel1(String input, String[] vowels) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
            if (input.contains(vowels[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```